# Deploy ASP MVC application with existing database on Azure

Tags: asp.net, .net, azure, deployment, webdeploy

I have database define in App_Data folder. Is it possible to deploy my app with database included App_Data if folder? Or update azure db automatically? Or if it isn't possible what's the best way to update azure db manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**first solution for you**

if you work with the entity framework, you can do the direct update, in the first step you have to replace the DB connection string in Web.config:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=OnlineAuctionDb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\OnlineAuctionDb.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

by connection string of database in azure

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=database;User Id=user@xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Password=mypassword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

after if you publish check this value "selected Run the code First Migrations" as you see in this picture

[image]

In the last step, you click on the Publish button

**Second solution for you**

you should get the SQL script from your local database and run it on your remote database . (don't forgot to change connection string in your web.config for test before publish )

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project directory， Open the *.csproj file and add the below code under the `Project` tag.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Content Include="App_Data\*">
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>always</CopyToPublishDirectory>
   </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

Then publish again, all the files under App_Data folder will be uploaded to azure.

We can also update our Azure Db in VS: [Tutorial: Build an ASP.NET app in Azure with SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-dotnet-sqldatabase#update-app-with-code-first-migrations)